# Getting DocumentID when decoding Firestore struct with custom decodable

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following struct

```
struct Vehicle: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String
}
```

As long as I use the default Swift decoder I can load Firestore entries without any issue (using `document.data(as:` ), and `id` contains the document ID.

However I now need a custom decode function inside that struct, and that's where things go wrong.

I can load all fields without any issue, but the document ID is not filled out.

I tried like this:

```
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    
        if let id = try container.decodeIfPresent(DocumentID<String>.self, forKey: .id) {
            self.id = id.wrappedValue
        }
```

But it gives me `nil`.

I found some other answers but they talk about `DocumentReference` which is a type that doesn't (or no longer?) exist.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't have a way to test, but see if the following works: `self._id = container.decode(DocumentID<String>.self, forKey: .id)`. (I'm assuming that you have `@DocumentID var id: String?` still)

Comment: But that's exactly what I have done? :)

Answer (score 5):

Decode the Document ID using:

```swift
_id = try container.decode(DocumentID<String>.self, forKey: .id)
```

for the corresponding variable:

```swift
@DocumentID var id: String?
```

This will place the document ID into the ID variable (note the required "_" before id).

Comment: Curious why `_id` works but not `self.id`?

Comment: Because _id is a property wrapper

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, a `DocumentReference` is an object that holds the path to a firestore document and is the object you would call your platforms equivalent of `.get()` to retrieve data through a `DocumentSnapshot`.
I am not terribly familiar with swift, but when decoding the object, you should be able to reference the ID as needed from the `documentID` property rather than the `.data()` method

Source: [iOS Document Snapshot ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#documentid)

Comment: But in my init method I do not have access to the source document. That would require quite a bit of refactoring.
Fact is that it works perfectly without a custom decoder.

Comment: how can it work if you don't have access to the source document?
All you need is a path to the document in question, and you say it works fine. you should be able to construct your decoder from the information present. the docID is just a value that is next to the data() method which means its not accessible from the data() method but is parent property from it.

Comment: It works fine with the standard decoder, it doesn't with a custom decoder (or at least I don't know how). I don't know what you're on about. It should be doable with a custom decoder too in that case.